# Is it possible to query the launch services database for applications that will open an arbitrary file or UTI type?

Tags: macos, osx-lion

I am able to use mdls to show the [Uniform Type Identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Type_Identifier) (UTI) for an arbitrary file as well as the hierarchy of types that are supersets of a specific UTI.

```
mac:~ mike$ mdls -name kMDItemContentType -name kMDItemContentTypeTree foo.ksh
kMDItemContentType     = "public.ksh-script"
kMDItemContentTypeTree = (
    "public.ksh-script",
    "public.shell-script",
    "public.script",
    "public.source-code",
    "public.plain-text",
    "public.text",
    "public.data",
    "public.item",
    "public.content"
)
mac:~ mike$ mdls -name kMDItemContentType -name kMDItemContentTypeTree foo.command
kMDItemContentType     = "com.apple.terminal.shell-script"
kMDItemContentTypeTree = (
    "com.apple.terminal.shell-script",
    "public.shell-script",
    "public.script",
    "public.source-code",
    "public.plain-text",
    "public.text",
    "public.data",
    "public.item",
    "public.content"
)
```

**Are there any tools that can show which Apps have registered for a particular UTI other than trial and error?**

It's clear from inspection that the `foo.command` file will be opened by Terminal.app, but it's not at all clear that foo.ksh currently belongs to TextEdit.app.

I'd like to be able to read the Mac OS X [Launch Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/Reference/reference.html) database directly without actually resorting to using `open` to see which app is chosen on a per UTI basis. It would be like having `--preview --verbose` switches to get open to tell me what is would do rather than doing it.

Even better would be a way to list all apps that could open that UTI, even if they are not the preferred app.

To get this secondary information, I have to create or find a file for each type of interest and use Finder to manually show which apps could open that UTI.

[image]

I would really like to be able to access this data programatically from the terminal.

Comment: The zsh completion seems interesting, but I don't see how to get that as stdout. I'll look into the AppApplications source code and see if the binary works on Lion or I can get it compiled. It's a great pair of leads - thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Andrew Mortensen’s [duti](https://github.com/moretension/duti) is a CLI that will list UTI handlers:

- `-d <uti>` lists the default handler;
- `-l <uti>` lists all registered handlers.

See the [man page for duti](http://duti.sourceforge.net/duti.1.php).

EDIT: as Lri points out in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/316490/access-finders-open-with-menu-from-the-commandline-for-tab-completion/316799#316799), duti does not seem to list all possible applications (possibly because it does not take account of UTI inheritance? That would be a matter for further inquiry). His solution, [AllApllications](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507000602/http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/AllApplications/AllApplications.html) (archive.org) would give a more complete answer.

Comment: It's missing some apps that would be displayed in the open with menu though.

Comment: Very odd. Could you tell me which ones it is missing?

Comment: I edited [my answer in the other question](http://superuser.com/questions/316490/access-finders-open-with-menu-from-the-commandline-for-tab-completion/316799#316799) to include example output from duti.

Comment: While duti is nicely written, it now uses deprecated APIs. I recommend to take a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/

Comment: OK - installing this by homebrew knocks a home run. Thanks so much!

Comment: The sourceforge URL for `duti` is dead; the current version seems to be hosted [here](https://github.com/moretension/duti).

Answer (score 13):

You can use this command to examine the launch services database. The -dump option gives you the entire database, then you can pipe this into grep and search for whatever you like.

`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -dump | grep -n7 'your search string'`

Comment: I'll probably need to ask a follow on question how to process this dump to spit out the app bundle or the location of the specific mdimporter file that parses a specific kMDItemContentType - but this has helped greatly. Thank you