# Command to list all apps capable of opening a given extension

Tags: windows, macos, command-line, terminal, file-extension

I'm building a file catalogue app of sorts, and for one of its uses I'd like to get a list of all apps currently installed capable of opening files with the extension of the currently selected file. So, say I've got a `.docx` file selected, the app would list apps like MS Word, OpenOffice, LibreOffice.
How would I get such a list on both Mac & Windows?

Answer (score 1):

For Windows:
There is no easy way, but a script can be written to enumerate the capabilities of each application registered. The list of official / Registered applications are stored in these two registry keys:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\RegisteredApplications
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\RegisteredApplications

Universal Web apps seem to register the entries in Location #1 above.

The right-pane lists each application that's registered with the "Default Programs" UI in Windows.

For example, Firefox adds an entry there, with the value data mentioned as:

Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\FIREFOX.EXE\Capabilities

So, the above location under HKCU or HKLM has the information on which file types and Protocols the program can handle.

Going to the location:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\FIREFOX.EXE\Capabilities

There is a subkey named "FileAssociations" which specifies the list of file types it can handle, and mentions the ProgIDs to use for each file type.

A script can be written which enumerates each registered application, and then enumerate each file type it can handle.

(Note: The "Open with" dialog in Windows does all this work.)

(Or)

Open Default Programs > Set your Default programs.
Select a program in the list, and click "choose defaults for this program"
This lists the files types the program can handle.
Do this for every application listed.

Answer (score 0):

For the Mac, there's another question/answer here on SuperUser that seems to solve this: [Is it possible to query the launch services database for applications that will open an arbitrary file or UTI type?](https://superuser.com/questions/323599)

The trick seems to be getting the "UTI" first (kind of like a mimetype), then looking up apps that can open it using [duti](http://duti.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: This page on `lsregister` seems useful too: http://krypted.com/mac-security/lsregister-associating-file-types-in-mac-os-x/