# OS X: Terminal command to check a file's default application

Tags: macos, shell-script, file-association

I'm writing a script which opens some files, in their default applications, via the `open` command. Before I actually open a file, though, I'd like to check which application is listed as its default and perform some actions based on the result. This is easy enough to check in Finder (in "Get Info" under "Open With"). Is there a way to obtain the same information via shell commands?

Comment: This is almost (but not quite) a duplicate of ["Is it possible to query the launch services database for applications that will open an arbitrary file or UTI type?"](https://superuser.com/questions/323599/is-it-possible-to-query-the-launch-services-database-for-applications-that-will) (that one's about getting *all* apps that can open a type). It looks like the answer to that question, an open-source tool named [duti](https://github.com/moretension/duti), may answer this one as well.

Comment: Perfect, that looks like exactly what I'm looking for!