# Command line tool to print out path of an app

Tags: macos

I need to know the path of Xcode.app. Spotlight knows where to find .apps, so there is a system on MacOS to find such things. Is there a command line tool that would provide this information e.g.:

```
$ tool Xcode
/Applications/Xcode.app
```

Comment: Related, this answer: [Access Finder's “Open With” menu from the commandline (for tab completion)](http://superuser.com/questions/316490/access-finders-open-with-menu-from-the-commandline-for-tab-completion/316799#316799)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Access the Spotlight database from the command line, searching for applications named "Xcode":

```
mdfind "kMDItemDisplayName==Xcode&&kMDItemKind==Application"
```

To view the Spotlight metadata for a given file or folder, use `mdls`, e.g. `mdls /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app`.

---

Alternatively, you can use AppleScript to get the path if Xcode is running.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Xcode"
        set a to application file
        POSIX path of a
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: `POSIX path of (path to app "Xcode")` would be faster than System Events and work even if the app is not open.

Comment: @Lri Thanks, I knew this was possible, but didn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
sudo find / -name 'Xcode'
```

you can also use regex in the name of the thing you're looking for if you're using quotes.

Comment: The name is `Xcode.app`. Additionally, this takes forever.

Answer (score 0):

If the app is somewhere on your path, you can use 'type':

```
jrobert$ type g++
g++ is /usr/bin/g++
```

Otherwise you'll need to use 'find' (or one of the several OS-X file-finders).

Comment: Mac OS X graphical applications are not usually on the `$PATH`.

Comment: Not the .apps, no, but since the OP uses Xode in his example, it's worth mention for finding the accomanying command-line development tools.